# Conflict org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest; and org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-test, spring-boot-test, junit-jupiter

I'm developing a spring boot app.
In my build.gradle I have added the dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

to use MockMultipartFile in my service:

```
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
...
...
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
        file.getName(), "image/jpeg", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

But now in the testing class I have this error:

[image]

This is my build.gradle:

dependencies {

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.11.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.11.Final'
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.0.1'


compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0'
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1'
compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'

compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'
testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.0')

compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.13.0'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

}

Comment: No idea if that has any impact, but you added spring-test as dependency to compile, usually it should be testCompile or testImplementation

Comment: I tried to compile spring-test with testCompile or testImplementation but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a quite old version of Spring Test:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
```

I assume Spring Test 3.1.1 did not yet have the JUnit JUpiter `SpringExtension`. Either update `spring-test` to [a more recent version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test) or remove it from your `build.gradle` and let Spring Boot with the [Spring Boot Starter Test manage](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-with-spring-boot-starter-test/) the dependency version of `spring-test`.

So your updated `dependencies` section could look like the following:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

// this is your testing swiss-army knife - take a look at its transitive dependency
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.11.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.11.Final'
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.0.1'


compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0'
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1'
compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'

compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

// REMOVE (managed by Spring Boot Starter Test) testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'
// REMOVE (managed by Spring Boot Starter Test) testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.0')

compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.13.0'
// REMOVE compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

Comment: Thanks rieckpil  for the reply! I made the changes you recommended. I solved the problem in the test class but now I don't have this import anymore:

`import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;`

and I can't use:

`MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
        file.getName(), "image/jpeg", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));`

Comment: I have found the solution rieckpil . I followed your advice and then i have implemented the MockMultipartFile class in one of my packages thanks to this [link](https://github.com/srcclr/test-java-gradle/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/mock/web/test/MockMultipartFile.java), eliminating the import.